# Run PHP script with Docker container

Tags: php, docker, cron, command-line-interface

I have a setup with `docker-compose` using nginx with php7-fpm. This is running and my PHP page is working fine. Now I need to execute some php scripts in a Cron Job, but I do not want to install php on the host machine, where I plan to install the Cron Jobs.

How can I run the php scripts using the php7-fpm docker container?

On my old system I had installed php7 so I could setup a cron task like this:

`0 2     * * *   /usr/bin/php /var/www/page/cron/my_php_script.php >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, but I will do it navigating to the folder of the project and executing `docker-compose exec`. Example:

```
0 2 * * *   cd /my/project/folder && docker-compose exec -T php-fpm-container php -f /my/project/folder-inside-container/cron/my_php_script.php >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Some important points to here:

1. There should be a `docker-compose.yml` with the environment you setted up (if not you can use the flag `-f` to point to the docker-compose file)
2. `php-fpm-container` should be the name of your service/container with the php-fpm installation
3. If you want to pipe the logs to a file the folder should be mounted so you can access it from outside the container. Or you can pipe output to `/dev/stdout` so it can be accessed by `docker-compose logs` command.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rebuild your docker-container according to your requirements & add crontab to inside the container if you're planning on using it more.

Alternatively, you can use dockers [exec command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), this allows you to execute a command inside a specified container. Your crontab could run the `docker exec` with your PHP-Command.